# Why do I get an exception when accessing my sprite members in this fashion?

Tags: xna, c#, 2d

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` error on the line where I do `new Vector2(...)`.

I think the problem is with the variables I'm using even though they're working to control the player sprite, so surely they can't be null, right? That is, however, in a different class and is initialized at the top of this one.

Here is the method in question:

```
public void Shoot()
{
    //if bullet delay resets then shoot
    if (bulletDelay >= 0)
        bulletDelay--;

    //if bullet delay is 0 then create a bullet at player bulletPosition
    if (bulletDelay <= 0)
    {
        //Here I create the new bullet passing in the texture and then modifying the bulletPosition were the bullet will appear from
        bullets newBullet = new bullets();
        bulletPosition = new Vector2(mySprite.imgX, mySprite.imgY);

        newBullet.isVisible = true;
        //These two lines mean that you can have no more that 20 bullets on screen at once
        if (bulletList.Count < 20)
        {
            bulletList.Add(newBullet);
        }
    }

    //reset bullet delay
    if (bulletDelay == 0)
        bulletDelay = 10;
}
```

`bulletDelay` is so the player can't spam the shoot button and have it be too easy. I tried to add a breakpoint on that line, when I run the program and hit the space bar that runs the `Shoot()` method the program stops and tells me about the error. When I hover over though it still says they are null.

I had the instances of the classes in the following code below. I've changed it so they are in the Shoot() method and all seems to well however I'm curious as to why the below code wasn't the correct way to do it:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    mySprite = new PlayerSprite();
    bulletList = new List<bullets>();
}
```

Comment: If mySprite isn't null then mySprite.imgX or .imgY might be. Can you add a breakpoint on that line then inspect the variable?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint on your error line to check which variables are null.

Comment: Yes the site notifies you if there is a new comment on a post you commented on. Try to put your variable declaration back in the Initialize method, and place a breakpoint there to see if that code is even called at some point

Comment: @Basaa I've added a breakpoint there but it seems to just skip over it there like it's not there. I also tried calling the initialize method in Game1 to be sure but still seems to just skip over it.

Comment: @Shmink I'm not sure if this suggestion applies well to XNA (also, C# is better about this than C++ in general), but the reason the debugger skipped over the suspect line of code may be because you are running a Release build, or one with optimizations enabled.  Be sure you're running a specific Debug build.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible sub-expressions on the line in question (`bulletPosition = new Vector2(mySprite.imgX, mySprite.imgY)`) are in the access of `mySprite`, which means that when that expression is executed, `mySprite` is null.

Even though you might see code elsewhere in your program that initializes a variable called `mySprite`, that may not fix the problem for any of the following reasons (and more):

- That `mySprite` may be a complete different variable than the `mySprite` you are currently accessing.
- That variable might be the same class member, but you might be initializing one instance of the class and not another, and the crash is occurring when `Shoot` is called for the latter instance.
- The code might be initializing the proper variable for the proper instance, but is never called for one reason or another.

And so on. There are really several reasons this can happen, and walking through all possibilities isn't really viable here.

The *correct solution* is to ensure that `mySprite` is non-null before you access it. The way to arrive at that solution is to learn how to use your debugger to do things like [set breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [examine the state of variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esta7c62%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), as well as to understand the context of your code and the differences between [objects and their types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173110.aspx).